# Making a star in python turtle

Tags: python, function, draw, turtle-graphics

I've been trying to make a star in python, but all i keep getting is some zig zag lines. My code is:

```
import turtle
star = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(800, 600)
wn.tracer(0)
star.pensize(10)
star.hideturtle()
wn.bgcolo("green")
star.color(white)

def draw_stars(x, y, size):
    star. goto(x, y)
    star.forward(78)
    star.left(144)
    star.forward(78)
    star.right(144)
    star.forward(78)
```

I wrote that , but I do not see where the star should be turning on angles when i run this program and turtle is opened.

Comment: Leave out `wn.tracer(0)`, it turns off animation. You'll see what's going on more easily if you see the turtle performing each move/turn sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle

my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
size = 200

for _ in range(5):
    my_turtle.forward(size)
    my_turtle.left(144)
```

or without `for`

```
import turtle

my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
size = 200

my_turtle.forward(size)
my_turtle.left(144)
my_turtle.forward(size)
my_turtle.left(144)
my_turtle.forward(size)
my_turtle.left(144)
my_turtle.forward(size)
my_turtle.left(144)
my_turtle.forward(size)
my_turtle.left(144)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from turtle import *
hideturtle()


def draw_star(sidesize, points, alfacorner, color):
    betacorner = 360/points+alfacorner
    fillcolor(color)
    begin_fill()
    for x in range(points*2):
        forward(sidesize)
        if x % 2 == 0:
            left(180-alfacorner)
        else:
            right(180-betacorner)
    end_fill()


draw_star(70, 8, 90, 'grey')
draw_star(90, 5, 72, 'yellow')
draw_star(120, 5, 36, 'red')
draw_star(65, 6, 60, 'darkblue')
draw_star(80, 4, 45, 'darkviolet')
draw_star(80, 3, 30, 'greenyellow')
draw_star(80, 6, 0, 'black')
```